# How to clear static vars in an application that is tested with JUnit/Robotium tests?

Tags: java, android, junit, integration-testing, robotium

I am writing auto tests (Robotium with ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2) for a code base which has a lot of legacy code containing static variables and want to make sure that the state we start with in each test is the same.

The way that we clear the static variables is by killing the whole process and then restarting it. This works well for the application itself, but when running the test project it results in us getting "Crash of app com.***_*** running instrumentation" in the console and the following lines in logcat:

```
03-05 11:08:01.113: I/ActivityManager(70): Process com.____________ (pid 662) has died.
03-05 11:08:01.113: W/ActivityManager(70): Crash of app com.___________ running instrumentation
```

Does anyone know if there is an alternative way to clear the variables (without having to go through them one by one) or another way to solve this issue?

Here are some more lines from logcat:

```
03-05 11:07:59.553: D/____________(662): NEW STATE FROM SERVICE: STATE_SHUTTING_DOWN
03-05 11:07:59.613: I/TestRunner(662): finished: testLoginCorrectUserNameIncorrectPassword(com.____________.test.LoginScreenTest)
03-05 11:07:59.613: I/TestRunner(662): passed: testLoginCorrectUserNameIncorrectPassword(com.____________.test.LoginScreenTest)
03-05 11:07:59.613: I/TestRunner(662): started: testLoginIncorrectUserName(com.____________.test.LoginScreenTest)
03-05 11:07:59.643: I/ActivityManager(70): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.____________/.____________ } from pid 662
03-05 11:08:00.183: D/dalvikvm(150): GC_CONCURRENT freed 185K, 51% free 2846K/5703K, external 957K/1462K, paused 3ms+102ms
03-05 11:08:01.075: D/____________(662): NEW STATE FROM SERVICE: STATE_TERMINATED
03-05 11:08:01.083: I/Process(662): Sending signal. PID: 662 SIG: 9
03-05 11:08:01.113: I/ActivityManager(70): Process com.____________ (pid 662) has died.
03-05 11:08:01.113: W/ActivityManager(70): Crash of app com.____________ running instrumentation ComponentInfo{com.____________.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
03-05 11:08:01.123: D/AndroidRuntime(654): Shutting down VM
03-05 11:08:01.123: I/ActivityManager(70): Force stopping package com.____________ uid=10034
03-05 11:08:01.173: D/dalvikvm(654): GC_CONCURRENT freed 117K, 71% free 300K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+1ms
03-05 11:08:01.173: D/jdwp(654): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
03-05 11:08:01.173: D/dalvikvm(654): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-05 11:08:01.193: I/dalvikvm(654): JNI: AttachCurrentThread (from ???.???)
03-05 11:08:01.193: I/AndroidRuntime(654): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
03-05 11:08:01.252: W/InputManagerService(70): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40980df8
03-05 11:08:01.372: D/dalvikvm(219): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 14K, 50% free 2868K/5639K, external 4235K/5259K, paused 44ms
```

Thankful for any help,

Tord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly i think you are going to be in trouble here, I do not believe there is an easy way to do this as your tests and your application share the same process when using instrumentation so you cannot use your current method to provide the results you want unless you run one test at a time. You could do this with the adb instrument command and run each test singularly and then restart the process, this will make your tests slow (probably very slow because of the default test runners package searching, but you can change this so that you only scan certain packages for tests)

The second option you have is as you think to set the statics to a default value, this will always be painful because no automated way is going to know which statics need resetting and which need to stay as they are.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will wait for the developers to clear the static vars so that we can shut down the application in a better way. In the meantime i will simply create one large test that contains everything, but that can easily be run as different tests later on.

Answer (score 0):

[ReflectionTestUtils](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html) will help but it doesn't solve your requirement of `one-by-one`